# Setting partial data to the series for the time range

Tags: lightweight-charts

How can I update the partial date range in lightweight-charts series? setData only updates the whole dataset, but I want just to set or update additional 100 entries to/in 1000 entries dataset that is currently loaded as part of responsive update.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is impossible right now. You can save your data somewhere outside of the library, and then set that all data to the library, something like that:

```js
let data = [];
series.setData(data);

// ...

data = [...newData, ...data];
series.setData(data);
```